# Let $u_n=\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \frac{\binom nr}{x+r}$ at $x=2$. Then find the sum to infinity of $u_1+u_2..$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Can I get a hint on how to begin the solution? I tried all possible derivative/integral methods of forming the general sum using the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, but I am just not able to the get $2+r$ in the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that,

\begin{gather*}
( 1-x)^{n} =\sum ^{n}_{r=0}( -1)^{r} \cdot ^{n} C_{r} x^{r}\\
x( 1-x)^{n} =\sum ^{n}_{r=0}( -1)^{r} \cdot ^{n} C_{r} x^{r+1}\\
\int ^{1}_{0} x( 1-x)^{n} dx=\int ^{1}_{0}\sum ^{n}_{r=0}( -1)^{r} \cdot ^{n} C_{r} x^{r+1} dx\\
=\sum ^{n}_{r=0}\int ^{1}_{0}( -1)^{r} \cdot ^{n} C_{r} x^{r+1} dx\\
For\ LHS,\\
\int ^{1}_{0} x( 1-x)^{n} dx=\int ^{1}_{0}( 1-x) \cdot ( 1-( 1-x))^{n} dx\\
=\int ^{1}_{0} x^{n}( 1-x) dx=\frac{1}{n+1} -\frac{1}{n+2}\\
For\ RHS,\\
\sum ^{n}_{r=0}\int ^{1}_{0}( -1)^{r} \cdot ^{n} C_{r} x^{r+1} dx=\sum ^{n}_{r=0}( -1)^{r} \cdot \frac{^{n} C_{r}}{r+2}\\
So,\ as\ per\ your\ question,\ \\
u_{n} =\frac{1}{n+1} -\frac{1}{n+2}\\
for\ n=1\ to\ n=\infty .
\end{gather*}
Can you now complete the telescoping series and show that the result is 1/2?

Comment: The OP wanted the sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$, but otherwise, this is OK.

Comment: @NoNames Never mind.

Comment: Yeah, I did reach till this point but it was an awkward integral so I thought it was wrong. Just for clarification, you used $\int_0^a f(x)=\int_0^a f(x-a)$ right?

Comment: **Editorial.** If you insist on using "old-style" $^n C_r$ *(I wouldn't do because the OP doesn't)*, better put it in braces (compare $\color{red}{a\cdot ^n C_r}$ `a\cdot ^n C_r` vs. $\color{blue}{a\cdot{^n C_r}}$ `a\cdot{^n C_r}`). Also, if you insist on intermixing text and math *(again, not necessary here at all IMO)*, consider using `\text{...}`.

Comment: @AdityanYes, I did.